# JUJU MAAS Bootstrap all on VM

Tags: juju, maas

1) I have maas server on Vm with 4 node all ubuntu 14.04 trusty
2) I have another VM as JUJU server i tried to bootstrap juju i got this error:

ERROR bootstrap failed: cannot upload bootstrap tools: Juju cannot bootstrap because no tools are available for your environment.
You may want to use the 'tools-metadata-url' configuration setting to specify the tools location.

any suggestion?

Comment: Rastin, great answer. I noticed in the web documentation that it shows: juju --sync-tools
or juju bootstrap --sync-tools both of which don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two commands worked for me:

```
juju sync-tools --show-log 
juju bootstrap --debug
```